# Swift UIButton action and GestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to solve this problem but I don't understand how to do it.
I have a view controller in which I have a view (CanvasView) and three buttons. Each button draw a type of shape. I want the user with a click of a button to add a shape with a tap in a certain point of the CanvasView only when the button is clicked.

Is it possible to allow tapGesture only when the button is clicked?

Here is the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var CanvasView: CanvasView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap(_:)))
    tapGR.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    CanvasView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    CanvasView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGR)
}

@IBAction func tap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let tapPoint = sender.location(in: CanvasView)
    let shapeView = ShapeSquare(origin: tapPoint)
    CanvasView.addSubview(shapeView)
}

@IBAction func DrawSquare(_ sender: UIButton) {
    CanvasView.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question but please note that it is standard practice that all variable and function names start with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the gesture disabled until the button is tapped.

Start by making the gesture a property:

```
var tapGR: UITapGestureRecognizer!
```

Then update `viewDidLoad`:

```
tapGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap(_:)))
tapGR.isEnabled = false
```

Then in your button handler:

```
tapGR.isEnabled = true
```